# Does anyone know what this symbol means on this functional diagram for the Faulhaber MCDC 3002?

Tags: motor-controller, block-diagram

I have this functional diagram of of the [Faulhaber MCDC 3002 motor controller](https://www.faulhaber.com/fileadmin/Import/Media/EN_7000_05029.pdf) operating in current control mode. I can't work out what the block highlighted in yellow is actually doing. Is it an absolute value of `I_act`, or something else?

[image: Functional Diagram]